# Stopping Raffle Smart Contract

Tags: solidity, remix

A smart contract has an enter() function where participants can send 1 Ethereum to enter a raffle. Is there an easy way to stop allowing the others calling this function while the winner is picked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a "pauseable" function modifier to any of the functions which you want to control access to.

Here is an example of how to implement this from [Open-Zeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/lifecycle/Pausable.sol).

You can then use it in your contract like so:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

import "path/to/Pausable.sol";

contract MyPausableContract is Pausable {

    myFunction() whenNotPaused {
        do things...
    }

}
```

To explain what is happening simply:

- There is a global variable which tracks if we are "paused" or "not paused" (bool)
- Then there is a function modifier which simply requires that the global variable is in the "not paused" state

  ```
  require(!paused);
  ```
- Then there is a function which can only be called by a privileged user which can change the value of the paused variable.

Comment: I added a bit more detail too at the end. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that solidity allows to use if statements. I'm still learning it. 
I went on a different way and basically

```
bool Pause; 

function setPause(bool anInput) public limited {
Pause = anInput; }
```

(limited is a modifier which I declared to check if the msg.sender is the contract owner)

```
function enter() public payable {
if (Pause == false) {
...do that...}
else{
revert("raffle is in pause. We are picking the winner"); }
```